# What's wrong with the voting restrictions?

Tags: support, voting

Today I reached my "daily" limit of votes. I was told to wait one hour before I could vote again. Last time I had to wait four hours. Why?

Comment: Stack Exchange runs in UTC, so it is likely different from your timezone, and votes renew based on it being a new day in UTC, so that is likely what you are seeing, unless both days you ran out at the same time, in which case that could be a further problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Votes roll over at a set time; specifically, 0:00 [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The timer for resetting your daily vote limit is counting down to that; today, you ran out of votes at 23:00 UTC. Previously, it happened at 20:00. That's all.

To see the current time in UTC and adjust for your time zone, [consult one of dozens of highly ranked google search results.](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about this, but what exactly is UTC time?

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms, UTC is similar to GMT, it's essentially the time from which time zones are derived.  For instance, I live in the US, in the central time zone, which is currently UTC-6 hours.  You can check UTC time on any Stack Exchange site - click the little "Achievements" menu (the bar graph icon where you see rep changes), and it will be in light gray in the upper right hand corner.

Comment: @agent86 Unless you're somewhere like Indiana, aren't you UTC-5 because of DST?